# I wont to get private key from SSL Certificate

Tags: security, openssl, ssl-certificate, private-key

I have SSL Certificate file but I not have private key file that is previously used for enable HTTPS. so how can I able to get back my private key from that SSL Certificate and csr file.

Please help me is there any way to get back my private key.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. By design, if the private key has been lost, there is no way to recover it from either the SSL certificate or the CSR.

Answer (score 0):

refer this

http://www.entrust.net/knowledge-base/technote.cfm?tn=7905 it may be useful for you

Comment: Thanks for your reply but its not work for me. might be I need to request for re-issue certificate.